# scrapy: Middleware/Pipeline single instance

Tags: python, scrapy

I am creating a local response cache for which I am creating a `Pipeline` because I need to store information of an item depending on its ID, collected from a site.

Now I also need to create a `Downloader Middleware` because depending on the ID that I previously stored, I don't want to hit the site with a new `Request`, so I am intercepting the `Request` before being sent to the server, check if the ID already exists on my cache, and if yes, then only return the same item from my cache.

Now as you see both `Pipeline` and `Middleware` need to work together, so separating doesn't seem very clean (also I have variables on both that I want to be unique), but when I setup both on their respective settings:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'myproject.urlcache.CachePipelineMiddleware': 1,
}

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'myproject.urlcache.CachePipelineMiddleware': 800,
}
```

I get two different instances (checking a log message on the constructor, so it gets created twice).

How can I make sure only one instance gets created and that I won't conflict with `Pipeline` and `Downloader Middleware` functionality of my project?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just realized this is a simple `Singleton` problem, and `scrapy` would actually work with the same instance for Pipeline and Middleware.

I am creating this `Singleton` Class first:

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]
```

And then, on the class for the Pipeline/Middleware I am adding the following:

```
class CachePipelineMiddleware(object):

    __metaclass__ = Singleton

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # it works as a Pipeline

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        # it works as a Middleware
```

Comment: Just asking - is there any reason to prefer using metaclass to handling the singleton directly in `CachePipelineMiddleware` (`__new__` method) for this simple case?

Comment: none really, I just created the Singleton class so it can be used for different things on my project. Any Singleton implementation won't conflict with the scrapy engine.